# QLineEdit does not get the value after using it

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlineedit

I trying to reuse the line edit after entering the first pin, im trying to reconfirm the pin, but when im getting the values from line edit, it returns blank

```
confirmPinPass(self)
     

def confirmPinPass(self):
    print("confirmPinPass")
    self.askpin_lbl.setText("Enter your Pin/Password:")
    self.pinpass_le.clear()

    self.ok_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: reconfirmPinPass(self))

def reconfirmPinPass(self):
    print("reconfirmPinPass")
    pinpassword = self.pinpass_le.text()

    print("pinpass",pinpassword)
    self.askpin_lbl.setText("Confirm your Pin/Pass")
    self.pinpass_le.clear()
    self.ok_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: checkPassFromConfirm(self, pinpassword))

def checkPassFromConfirm(self, password):
    print("checkPassFromConfirm")

    self.pinpassword2 = self.pinpass_le.text()
    print("pinpass2", self.pinpassword2)
    print("pinpass2: ", self.pinpassword2,"pinpass: ", password)

    if  self.pinpassword2 != password:
  #reask pin pass
        confirmPinPass(self)

    else:
        gotomenu(self)
```

in here
print("pinpass2: ", self.pinpassword2,"pinpass: ", password)
--------it return blank in pinpass 2 but pinpass have value and later when retrying both are blank---------

**terminal**

```
confirmPinPass
reconfirmPinPass
pinpass 1213
reconfirmPinPass
pinpass 1213
checkPassFromConfirm
pinpass2 
pinpass2:   pinpass:  1213
confirmPinPass
reconfirmPinPass
pinpass 1213
checkPassFromConfirm
pinpass2 
pinpass2:   pinpass:  1213
confirmPinPass
checkPassFromConfirm
pinpass2 
pinpass2:   pinpass:  1213
confirmPinPass
reconfirmPinPass
pinpass 
reconfirmPinPass
pinpass 1213
checkPassFromConfirm
pinpass2 
pinpass2:   pinpass:  1213
confirmPinPass
checkPassFromConfirm
pinpass2 
pinpass2:   pinpass:  1213
confirmPinPass
reconfirmPinPass
pinpass 
checkPassFromConfirm
pinpass2 
pinpass2:   pinpass:  1213
confirmPinPass
reconfirmPinPass
pinpass 
reconfirmPinPass
pinpass 
checkPassFromConfirm
pinpass2 
pinpass2:   pinpass:  
sendingpass:  
Opened database successfully(successful and go to menu)
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You must disconnect the signals before re-connecting them, otherwise they will be duplicated every time the signals are fired: `try: self.ok_btn.clicked.disconnect(); except TypeError: pass`.